# Quiero hacer un Toggle Switch en Ruby on Rails

Tags: bootstrap, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-switch

Quiero hacer un **Toggle Switch** en RoR

Mis versiones de ruby on rails son respectivamente:

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]
```

y

```
rails -v
Rails 5.1.3
```

Creé un proyecto con `scaffold`

```
rails new comprobar
cd comprobar
rails generate scaffold Articulo nombre:string titulo:string contenido:text comprobar:boolean
rails db:migrate
```

Que se puede visualizar en github: 
https://github.com/rrg1459/comprobar

---

Estoy usando la gema `bootstrap-switch-rails`

**NOTA: Si alguien tiene alguna otra gema y/o procedimiento en rails que
me pueda servir, con gusto sigo su sugerencia.**

Lo que he hecho hasta ahora es lo siguiente:

Siguiendo los pasos de la página: http://www.diogonunes.com/blog/bootstrap-switch-on-rails/

Copié la gema `bootstrap-switch-rails` a mi `gemfile` y otras dos más

```
gem 'bootstrap-switch-rails'
gem 'bootstrap3-rails', '~> 3.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
```

Copié el respectivo `js` y `style` usando `sass`, tal  y como indica la página referenciada y el código tal y como indica la página en el respectivo `_form.html.erb`

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').bootstrapSwitch();
  });
  </script>
<% end %>
```

---

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :comprobar %>
    <%= form.check_box :comprobar,
    :data => { :size=>'small', 'on-color'=>'success', 'on-text'=>'YES', 'off-text'=>'NO' } %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay dos problemas que te impiden utilizar correctamente la librería:

1. Necesitas *jQuery*, por lo tanto instala *jQuery* en tu proyecto (recuerda que Rails 5.1 ya no tiene *jQuery* por defecto). Puedes hacerlo de muchas maneras, acá te muestro como hacerlo con la gema `jquery-rails`:

   Agrega la gema `jquery-rails` en tu *Gemfile*:

   ```
   gem 'jquery-rails'
   ```

   Instálala con *Bundle*:

   ```
   $ bundle install
   ```

   Agrégala en tu archivo *application.js* **antes** de `bootstrap-switch`"

   ```
   //= require jquery
   //= require jquery_ujs
   //= require bootstrap-switch
   ```
2. Para utilizar `content_for` debes agregar el bloque `yield` para que el código sea incluido.

   Agrega el bloque `yield :head` en *application.html.erb*:

   ```
   <head>
     <title>Comprobar</title>
     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
     <%= yield :head %>
   </head>
   ```

Comment: @rrg1459 Te envié un _pull request_ al repositorio que publicaste con los ajustes mencionados.

Comment: Acepte el pull request, actualice la app y todavia no hace  el toggle.

Comment: `cd ..`

rmdir comprobar 
(borré la carpeta comprobar a través de windows)

`git clone https://github.com/rrg1459/comprobar.git`
(me cloné la app, para estar seguro de tener tus cambios)

`cd comprobar`

`bundle install`

`rails db:migrate`

`rails s`

Comment: @rrg1459 ¿Te muestra algún error en los logs del servidor o en la consola del navegador? ¿Pudiste abrir con éxito el  link con el ejemplo que puse en mi comentario anterior?

Comment: Articulo Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "articulos".* FROM "articulos"
  Rendered articulos/index.html.erb within layouts/application (17.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1605ms (Views: 1578.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/articulos/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-29 16:15:18 -0400
Processing by ArticulosController#new as HTML
  Rendering articulos/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered articulos/_form.html.erb (138.0ms)
  Rendered articulos/new.html.erb within layouts/application (158.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 331ms (Views: 312.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

Comment: Lo probé con éxito en los navegadores chrome y explorer, en firefox y opera no funciona, y por lo mismo no me funcionaba, porque mi navegador por defecto es firefox. ahora voy a dar por terminada la pregunta exitosamente, creo que es alguna configuración que me falta en firefox

Comment: @rrg1459 También creo que debe ser alguna configuració, probablemente relacionada con Windows, yo tuve éxito en los tres que probé (Incluyendo firefox), pero probé desde Mac.

Comment: recién encontré un código que modifica por completo el check_box de rails, sin necesidad de gemas, ni código adicional en ruby o en rails, como lo podría anexar a esta pregunta para referencia de futuros programadores???

Comment: @rrg1459 Puedes agregar otra respuesta a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución minimalista y sin código adicional sería agregar únicamente a app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss este código:

```
/*....................................................*/

$claro: #EEEED8;
$fondo: #0099E5;
$gris: #D3D3D3;
$oscuro: #8A8081;
$relleno: #000099;

input[type="checkbox"] {
  appearance: none;
  background-color: darken($claro, 2%);
  border: 1px solid $oscuro;
  border-radius: 26px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px $gris;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 14px;
  position: relative;
  transition: border .25s .15s,
              box-shadow .25s .3s,
              padding .25s;
  width: 33px;
  vertical-align: top;

  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }

  &:after {
    background-color: $claro;
    border: 1px solid $oscuro;
    border-radius: 24px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 3px hsla(0,0%,0%,.025),
                0 1px 4px hsla(0,0%,0%,.15),
                0 4px 4px hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    left: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 16px;
    top: 1px;
    transition: border .25s .15s,
                left .25s .1s,
                right .15s .175s;
  }
  &:checked {
    background-color: $fondo;
    border-color: $fondo;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 13px $fondo;
    padding-left: 18px;
    transition: background-color .25,
                border .25s,
                box-shadow .25s,
                padding .25s .15s;

    &:after {
      border-color: $relleno;
      background-color: $relleno;
      left: 16px;
      right: 1px;
      transition: border .25s,
                  left .15s .25s,
                  right .25s .175s;
    }
  }
}

/*....................................................*/
```

**NOTA:** *este cambio modifica automáticamente todos los check_box en la aplicación RoR.*